Cannot locate runfiles directory in bazel java
I have a genrule which takes in a java binary as a src and uses $(location ) as the cmd. When the genrule is executed, I get Cannot locate runfiles directory. (Set $JAVA_RUNFILES to inhibit searching.)
If I build the binary first and then execute the genrule, it works fine. How can I fix this?
Update: Adding the binary target to tools and removing from srcs fixed the problem

If the java_binary target will be invoked in the cmd attribute of the genrule, then the java_binary should be in the tools attribute of the genrule instead of the srcs:
BUILD:
java_binary(
  name = "Main",
  srcs = ["java/com/Main.java"],
)

genrule(
  name = "gen",
  tools = [":Main"],
  outs = ["out"],
  cmd = "$(location :Main) > $@",
)

Main.java:
package com;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hello world");
  }
}

$ bazel build out
INFO: Analyzed target //:out (1 packages loaded, 4 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:out up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/out
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.297s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action

$ cat bazel-bin/out
hello world

